# Is it appropriate to say おじゃまします when entering one's own room?

Tags: phrases

Let's say my friend is in my room and I am out in the kitchen.

At some time I decide to enter my room.

Is it appropriate to say おじゃまします when I am entering my own room?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not appropriate to use the phrase in that situation.  「邪魔{じゃま}する」 means "**to bother**", "**to disturb**", etc., which one would not be doing when entering one's own room.

A more suitable situation to say it would be like this.  Suppose there are your good friend and his/her gf/bf in your room when you are somewhere else.  ***As a joke***, you might say 「お邪魔します」 upon entering the room.

Outside of comedy, you will basically never say 「お邪魔します」 in your own home, even including when entering your parents' or sibling's room.